# How to create authors for wordpress by php programmatically?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there anyone who has the idea that how to create authors for wordpress by php programmatically?

Comment: Your question is pretty much very unclear , and here you will get the code problem's solutions , if you have any problem with code  then post it in your question and we are willing to help you. You should also check wordpress's official documentation which includes all of the api things http://codex.wordpress.org/

Comment: Would you please let us know your, why you want to create user like that way so we can provide solution accordingly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
$user_id = username_exists( $user_name );
if ( !$user_id and email_exists($user_email) == false ) {
    $random_password = wp_generate_password( $length=12, $include_standard_special_chars=false );
    $user_id = wp_create_user( $user_name, $random_password, $user_email );
    wp_update_user(array(
        'ID' => $user_id,
        'role' => 'Author'
    ));
} else {
    $random_password = __('User already exists.');
}
```